# Does Cobalt support webm progressive playback

Tags: cobalt

It seems that MediaSource and Progressive playback use the different demuxer. ChunkDemuxer is used for MediaSource,  ShellDemuxer is used for Progressive playback.

In ShellParser.cpp implementation:

```
PipelineStatus ShellParser::Construct(
        scoped_refptr<ShellDataSourceReader> reader,
        scoped_refptr<ShellParser>* parser,
        const scoped_refptr<MediaLog>& media_log) {
      DCHECK(parser);
      DCHECK(media_log);
      *parser = NULL;
      // download first 16 bytes of stream to determine file type and extract basic
      // container-specific stream configuration information
      uint8 header[kInitialHeaderSize];
      int bytes_read = reader->BlockingRead(0, kInitialHeaderSize, header);
      if (bytes_read != kInitialHeaderSize) {
        return DEMUXER_ERROR_COULD_NOT_PARSE;
      }
      // attempt to construct mp4 parser from this header
      return ShellMP4Parser::Construct(reader, header, parser, media_log);
    }
```

It seems that Cobalt can only demux MP4 container(**Only ShellMP4Parser**) for progressive playback.

Is it known status for Cobalt ?how can we support webm progressive playback on the device?

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt will not support WebM/VP9 progressive playback. We changed the Progressive Conformance test to change VP9 to H264. This will be pushed soon.
https://github.com/youtube/js_mse_eme/commit/d7767e13be7ed8b8bdb2efda39337a4a2fb121ba